# Multiple divs with margin to fill parent width

Tags: html, css, width, css-tables

I tried to make multiple divs to take up the whole width from the parent div. In order to do that I used `display:table` and `display:table-cell`. The problem with this method is that I can't add margin to the child divs in order to give some space between them. Now they are all stack together and it doesn't look good.

Any suggestions?

Here's the code:

```css
.parent {
      text-align:center;
      margin:0px;
      width:500px;
      padding:0px;
      background:blue;
      display:table;
      box-sizing:border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
      -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
      list-style-type:none;
    }
    
.child{
      padding:15px;
      background:#f00;
      display:table-cell;
      list-style-type:none;
    }
    
.child:nth-child(2n) {background:green;}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="child">sometext</div>
<div class="child">somemoretext</div>
<div class="child">sometext</div>
<div class="child">sometext</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried with flexbox? - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: No but I will . Thanks for the input.

Comment: Do you need to use table cells specifically? Otherwise you could use `display:inline-block` like in this fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/encxmrw4/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flexbox got you :) :

```css
  Body {background:cyan;}
.parent {
  text-align:center;
  margin:0px;
  width:100%;
  padding:0px;
  background:blue;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
 }
    
.child{
  padding:15px 25px;
  background:#f00;
  list-style-type:none;
  width:inherit;
  margin:5px;
}

.child:nth-child(2n) {background:green;}
```

```html
   <div class="parent">
<div class="child">sometext</div>
<div class="child">somemoretext</div>
<div class="child">sometext</div>
<div class="child">sometext</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
<div class="child">somemoretext</div>
<div class="child">sometext</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
<div class="child">somemoretext</div>
<div class="child">somemoretext</div>
<div class="child">sometext</div>
</div

>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input  I will modify  my code and let you know how this worked. :)

Comment: Thanks for your input. It was very useful. Now I improved the code to adjust the child width in order to fill the space. Because in the original code you were adjusting the space and not the width

Comment: great, glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [flexbox](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/)

**CSS**

```
.parent {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.child {
    padding:15px;
    background:#f00;
    margin-right: 16px;
}
.child:last-child {
    margin-right: 0px;
}
.child:nth-child(2n) {
    background:green;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/kd4kjdck/25/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can add space by adding `border` :

```css
.parent {
  text-align:center;
  margin:0px;
  width:500px;
  padding:0px;
  background:blue;
  display:table;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  list-style-type:none;
  
}

.child{
  padding:15px;
  background:#f00;
  display:table-cell;
  list-style-type:none;
  border-left:10px solid #fff;
  border-right:10px solid #fff;
}

.child:nth-child(2n) {background:green;}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="child">sometext</div>
<div class="child">somemoretext</div>
<div class="child">sometext</div>
<div class="child">sometext</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input but what I am looking  for was empty space not white.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using display: table and table-cell, **use display: inline-block;**. And then give the margins that you want.

.parent {

```
text-align:center;
margin:0px;
width:500px;
padding:0px;
background:blue;
display:inline-block;
box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
 list-style-type:none;
```

}

.child{

```
margin:5px;
background:#f00;
display:inline-block;
list-style-type:none;
```

}

.child:nth-child(2n) {

```
background:green;
```

}